# How to get universe, classes, objects, report names, report fields from SAP BO using Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sdk, business-objects

I am able to connect SAP BO server via java (SDK) after this I don't know queries to get all BO Metadata (universe name, classes, objects, report names, report columns, report variables separately like oracle) as I need store all BO metadata into my local database (MySQL) from BO server.

My expected output would be that how retrieve all BO Metadata in tabular form like SQL tables.

I am new to SAP BO. I was stuck on this. Please suggest any one on this. All leads are appreciable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      IEnterpriseSession enterpriseSession = null;
      try {
         // Establish connection
         System.out.println("Connecting...");
         IEnterpriseSession enterpriseSession = sessionMgr.logon(user, pass, host, auth);
         IInfoStore infoStore =(IInfoStore)enterpriseSession.getService("InfoStore");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to retrieve metadata from the BO Server is to use CMS queries. You can use CMS queries with the REST API.

A simple example to retrieve metadata from your universes in your cms:

- **API URL**: http://host:port/biprws/v1/cmsquery
- **HTTP Method**: GET
- **Data Formats**: Application/JSON, Application/XML
- **Headers**: x-sap-logontoken (you can retrieve a logontoken via the rest api as well)

if you use json use following request body:

{
 query:"select * FROM CI_APPOBJECTS WHERE SI_KIND='Universe' order by SI_NAME asc"
}

This blog is a good place to start:
https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/10/query-the-businessobjects-repository-using-bi-platform-rest-sdk-rws/

Comment: Your answer contains not much more than a link and might be deleted, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Why do we have to use REST API if we can directly get the data and assign it to objects via SDK?   For Eg:   IInfoObjects info = infoStore.query(sql);   Isn't this faster than web services